# Past perfect or past simple; present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

I'm writing an essay in which I have these sentences, but I am not sure what tense I should use (**past perfect** to show that some events happened earlier than other or **simple past** just to show facts in the past; **past simple** to show that event occurred in the past or **present perfect** to show the result):

> I remember that all my items **had been packed up** (were packed?) *by the time* of my departure. Then I relocated them to the ground floor. Having decided to check if I **hadn't forgotten** (didn't forget?) to pick up anything, I went to the room in which I **had lived** (lived?) for 2 weeks. It *turns out* that I **left** (have left? (as a finished action with a result in the present)) my rucksack in the corridor.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: While asking about the meanings of past perfect and past simple is a good question for ELL, requests to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are off-topic for ELL, especially requests to do "homework". If you could rework this question to be about your specific uncertainties about these two tenses, then it would be on topic. Please check for other similar questions on ELL. There have been so many questions on this topic already that there's a tag for "past-vs-past-perfect", which I have added to your question.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues, let's go sentence by sentence

**1st sentence:** change the order of the sentence, use the simple past (it happens at the same time while you remember)

- I remember that by the time of my departure all my things were
  packed.

**2nd sentence:** you move luggage, you don't really relocate it

- Then I moved them to the ground floor.

**3rd sentence:** past perfect (as the event leaving the backpack = rucksack has happened way before), also change to the room where I have stayed)

- I decided to check that I hadn't forgotten anything and went to the room where I had lived for 2 weeks. It turned out that I had left my backpack in the corridor.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of points that one could make about the writing here, but I'll focus just on your question relating to the bold items.

> I remember that all my items **had been packed up** (were packed?)by the
> time of my departure.

Both of these choices are fine. "Had been packed up" or "had been packed" in the past perfect sounds more like you're indicating that the packing happened prior to the time of departure; "were packed" sounds like you're using "packed" as a statal adjective - i.e., indicating that the bags were full of stuff, in the state of having being packed. The sentence is a bit awkward out of context (who packed the bags?) and a more natural phrasing would probably be available if I had context. I'm also not going to get into the difference between "packed" and "packed up" for present purposes.

> Having decided to check if I **hadn't forgotten** (didn't forget?) to pick
> up anything..."

I would rephrase that as "Having decided to check to make sure that I hadn't forgotten anything..." I prefer the past perfect here, since you're referring to the potential event (forgetting something) that would have taken place before the event being narrated (deciding to check). But past simple is also ok, since the order of events is clear from context.

> ...I went to the room in which I **had lived** (lived?) for 2 weeks.

Same answer as above. "Had lived" sounds better to me since it makes the order clear, but of course if you feel that the order of events is obvious, it's fine to use the simple.

> It turns out that I **left** (have left? (as a finished action with a
> result in the present)) my rucksack in the corridor.

Like above, you would use "had left" to make the order clear, but simple "left" is also an option. "Have left" is wrong. I've never heard of this "result in the present" idea, but if you're telling a story about things that all occurred at a specific time in the past, you would never use the present perfect.